# When use As+B in partial fraction expansion

Tags: laplace-transform

I'm trying to solidify my knowledge around using partial fraction expansion. In this specific case, when to use
$$ f(s) = \frac{As+B}{s^2+cs+d}$$
instead of using
$$ f(s) = \frac{A}{s+e}+\frac{B}{s+f}$$

Per "Control Engineering", 2nd ed. by W. Bolton, when we have quadratic factors in the denominator, and the quadratic does not factorize without imaginary terms we should use **As+B** for partial fraction expansion.

So, i made up and worked this problem below where i am applying 12V dc to a circuit (closing switch at t = 0) with the capacitor initially charged, and then solving for i(t):

[image]

R = 1Ω, L = 26.5mH (initial current = 0), C = 1000μF (initial voltage VC(0) = 5V), and V = 12 volts.

Solving for i(s) i get,
$$ i(s) = \frac{\frac{V-V_C(0)}{L}}{s^2+s\frac{R}{L}+\frac{1}{LC}}$$

Since the roots of the denominator are,
$$s=\frac{-b±\sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a}$$

We can see that we will get complex roots since,
$$\sqrt{b^2-4ac} = ±j\sqrt{\frac{R^2}{4L^2}-\frac{1}{LC}} = ±j194.23  $$

And the roots are thus,
$$s = -18.87±j194.23$$

In my case, i did the p.f.e. as follows,

$$\frac{\frac{V-V_C(0)}{L}}{s^2+s\frac{R}{L}+\frac{1}{LC}}=\frac{A}{s+18.87+j193.24}+\frac{B}{s+18.87-j193.24}    $$

Where,
$$A = \frac{12-5}{-\sqrt{R^2-4\frac{L}{C}}} = j0.683$$
$$B = \frac{12-5}{\sqrt{R^2-4\frac{L}{C}}} = -j0.683$$

$$i(s)=\frac{j0.683}{s+18.87+j193.24}+\frac{-j0.683}{s+18.87-j193.24}    $$
My solution ended up being,
$$ i(t)=1.366e^{-18.87t} sin(193.24t)$$

Which when plotted with a numerical simulation of this circuit was perfectly coincidental with the simulation result for i(t),
[image]

So, my solution factorized with imaginary terms, but i did not p.f.e. with As+B, and i still arrived at correct solution.

My specific question is thus, **when *must* we use p.f.e. with As+B?**

Comment: This isn't really an EE question. But to answer it. There's nothing wrong in solving it that way or using laplace inverse tables for the full denominator.

Comment: So we never **must** use As+B approach in p.f.e. of circuits problems? Thanks @Andyaka

Comment: @relayman357 Most of us aren't pushing the frontiers and working to expand Laplace tables. (You can do that work, but most of us accept the efforts of others unless we are just interested in pure mathematics.) If you cannot find a matching Laplace table entry for the higher-order form, then you use partial fraction expansion (and you are allowed to recombine some, if you want) until we can find the entries in the table and write out a solution. I'm not sure what else you want to know about it. Also, if you are talking to Andy, you'll need to use the '@' method to access his notifications.

Comment: Thanks @jonk, I can use the tables etc.  I'm just working on deeper look under the hood. Not sure my question is really pushing the frontiers.  For example, your Lambert(W) answer to a question a while back was above & beyond the "normal" stuff - and very much appreciated by me.

Comment: @relayman357 The partial fraction expansion is an exact equivalence. There is no difference between the left and right side of the equation. They are just in different forms. So the answer is always the same, if both sides have all of their entries in the Laplace table. Expand your solution into the partial fractions (I've not done this, but I'm sure you can) and then look up those simpler ones in the tables. Get the results from that, apply them, and then see if you can recombine to find that equivalence. You should be able to find it (you may need to draw upon trig identities to do so.)

Comment: @relayman357 When I was referring to "pushing the frontiers" what I meant was this: Even the most complete Laplace tables are actually incomplete in the sense that there are many fractions that haven't been solved, yet. No one knows because no one yet has discovered a solution (lack of time, interest, effort, or just plain 'too hard'.) In those cases, if you have such a complex fraction for which there is no known direct solution and for which at least one of the partial fractions also has no known solution, then you'd be doing such pure math to find one.

Comment: What values did you get for `A` and `B` in your example. **Where they complex conjugates?** If so, that might explain how you still ended up with the correct answer. Please add that info also into the question.

Comment: Yes @AJN, they were complex conjugates.  I edited my question and added values for A & B.

Comment: I agree with the above comment that this may be more suited to math.SE, but my guess is that we should use `As+B` format if we want the constants `A,B` to remain real numbers. The imaginary part in that case will be taken care by the `s`in `As+B`. We were also taught the `As+B` way to do p.f.e if factorisation was "***not***" possible.

Comment: Thanks @AJN.  I’ll keep working at it (and may go to math.SE).  Appreciate your input.

Comment: IIRC, only real rule (no pun intended) is that each term should be a proper fraction with numerator degree strictly lower than denominator degree; usually exactly one order less.

Comment: The accepted to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/994252/partial-fractions-decomposition/994258?r=SearchResults#994258) agrees with you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The choice depends on whether we want the constants to be real numbers or complex numbers.

A relevant portion from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_fraction_decomposition#Example_2)

> If K is field of complex numbers, the fundamental theorem of algebra implies that all \$p_i\$ have degree one, and all numerators \$a_{i j}\$ are constants. When K is the field of **real numbers**, some of the \$p_i\$ may be quadratic, so, in the partial fraction decomposition, **quotients of linear polynomials by powers of quadratic polynomials** may also occur.

[Example 2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_fraction_decomposition#Example_2) shows an explicit example. They do the p.f.e both with real constants and complex constants.

Comment: Thanks @AJN, very much appreciated!